# Splash screen with progress bar and a cancel button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to implement a splash screen in my application, like if the username and password are already saved in nsuserdefaults and username password fields are also filled up, then when the user starts his application, a splash screen with progress bar and a cancel button should come up, and application should be logged in automatically.

And in case if user clicks on the cancel button, that splash screen would be removed from view and the login screen would be shown.

Is there any example/tutorial related to this?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the purpose of the splash screen is to make the user wait until the application loads into the iOS. Of course you can achieve your requirement by placing an image and a cancel button. But I afraid that anyhow when your app is launched for the first time you wont get the control for upto 4 to 5 seconds. So my suggestion would be to fix a splash screen first (traditional one) and then when you get the control, perhaps in applicationDidFinishLaunching add a progress bar and a cancel button.